# Publish Android Library That Consume Bill of Materials

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, maven-bom

We are creating an android library (aar) for our internal needs, the library has dependencies to firebase services, and we are relying on the firebase bom to provide appropriate versions for every firebase dependency that we use(com.google.firebase:firebase-bom).

When we try to consume the library, we got a resolution error because the firebase dependencies don't contain version number:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:.
     Required by:
```

I wonder how to properly configure the pom of the library so that we can resolve the dependencies? Or it is not possible to begin with?

Thanks.

Comment: adding the firebase tag to this so that they can see it, i'm sure they'll update to the correct tag once they review your question